Why can't iron ionize to 1+?
I'm taking a chemistry course right now. I've learned about electron configuration and ionization and wondered why iron doesn't "like" ionizing to a 1+ state. When iron goes to 2+, the electron configuration is [Ar] 3d6, since both 4s2 electrons are lost due to being in the valence shell. $\ce{Fe^3+}$ is [Ar] 3d5, since a third electron is removed, and it is most stable to remove it from 3d such that all orbitals are filled with only one electron. But, why not 1+? See the following:

$\ce{Fe}$: [Ar] 4s2 3d6
$\ce{Fe+}$: [Ar] 4s1 3d6 -> [Ar] 4s2 3d5.

4s2 is very stable since the 4s is fully filled. And 3d5 is the second most stable 3d configuration, after 3d10. So, why doesn't iron ever ionize like so? One thought I had was that in order to go from [Ar] 4s1 3d6 to [Ar] 4s2 3d5, one 3d electron needs to go up an energy level (from 3 to 4), but a small amount of energy put into the system should stop that. I can't think of anything else that would stop $\ce{Fe+}$ from existing.
So, why isn't $\ce{Fe+}$ possible?

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139717/electron-configuration-of-ironi-cation

Iron(I) definitely exists. Example: Iron(I) hydride. It is just that it is not common.

Perhaps I should rephrase my question now. If it does exist, why isn't it as common as Fe2+ and Fe3+?

Yes that is a better question and you can somewhat find answer in these posts: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37402/why-fe-3-is-more-common-than-fe-2 .. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/175768/why-is-ironiii-more-stable-than-ironii

You dismiss that the reduction potentials of the elements, ions etc. are actually the [Gibbs free] energies of reactions with H2, H30+ under standard conditions.  The overall reaction involves lattice energies, solvation energies etc. not just the basic atomic states of the metallic ion. +1 ions of the transition elements tend to disproportionate to the metal and +2 and+3 ions because of the strong metallic bonds in the metals and the higher lattice and solvation energies in the higher charged ions. [also true for the alkalines, aluminum etc.]
